# Trouble with JSON.parse

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, coffeescript, mongoose

I have a string which I would like to turn into an object so I can pass it to `mongoose`

```
string = "{setting: {foo: false}}"

options = JSON.parse(string)
```

but this is giving me this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/blah/blah/blah.js:48:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/blah/blah/blah.js:54:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:83:25)
    at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:177:29)
    at fs.stat.notSources.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:152:18)
    at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON isnt right.

```
strthing ='{"setting": {"foo": false}}';
options = JSON.parse(strthing);

alert(options.setting.foo);  ----> False.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaXjk/

Comment: For others, the problem is with how I was using quotes, `'` and `"`. Thanks @3boll took me a min to realize thats what you were saying.